# Building a C dll to call from LabVIEW

Tags: c, dll, labview

I would like to write some advanced functions in C to then call from LabVIEW. As a trial I have started with a simple code and built a dll from it using code blocks. However, I have difficulties with the DLL in LabVIEW where I get an error 13 from the Call Library node.

"*LabVIEW: (Hex 0xD) Failed to load dynamic library because of missing external symbols or dependencies, or because of an invalid file format.*". [Image of implementation in LabVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxwE.png)

I have added the path of the DLL to the system environment variable

Here's the C code (function) used to build the dll

```
    int Addition(int a,int b)
{
    int out = 0;
    out=a+b;
    return out;
}
```

Hopefully , someone can help me with this novice issue .

Looking forward to your feedback , thanks.

Comment: adding `-static-libgcc`  to the compile arguments might help.

Comment: @Cosinus : Thanks a lot for your help . I got rid of the error , but the function wouldnt perform addition . So , I replaced the code to this :

`#include <stdio.h>

    void Addition(int a,int b , int c)
{
    c = a+b;
    return 0;
}`

But i still dont get a result in LabVIEW from runnign the DLL . Do you know what might cause this issue ?

Comment: I think what you want is this: `void Addition(int a, int b, int *c) { *c = a + b; return; }`
Make sure that in LV the return type is `void` and args are: `signed int32`, `signed int32`, `signed int32 ptr`. The result is stored in `c`

Comment: In your picture you used `8-byte double` which does not match `int`

Comment: @Cosinus : Appreciate your assistance and the corrections . Unfortunately the function outputs the value in c . I wired constants 15 and 5 to a and b , wired a constant of 0 to C . The output of C after execution is 0 . If I change the constant value of C to 10 I get 10 after execution . The data type and return type is correct and has been verified . LV function prototype is `void  Addition(int32_t a, int32_t b, int32_t *c); `

Comment: @Cosinus : I had success with this code :

`int Addition(int a, int b )
{
     return a + b ;
}
`
Thanks a lot for your help in my process and have a nice day !